# How to check in each log file in a UNIX folder for 'ERROR:' in SAS ?Log files are on UNIX

Tags: sas

Trying to to create a dataset with log file names and correspondig errors which contains 'ERROR:' in the log file.Log files are on UNIX and i want to access that unix path on SAS and search for 'ERROR:' string and create a dataset with log file name and Error.
I don't have a clue how to achieve that....Any help?

Thanks in advance,
Sam.

Here is an example what I'm looking for.For suppose I have a.log, b.log,c.log,...n.log files under /tcrsk/dev/Logs folder on UNIX.Trying for a program that loops thru all the log files and create a data set with 2 variables like this                                                        `LOg_Name ERROR_Message                                                                    a.log    ERROR:Missing                                                                        b.log    ERROR:No data set                                                                        c.log    ERROR:A lock is not avialable`                                                              I guess this example gives more details....

Comment: Need more information.  SAS is in unix, or in windows?  How do you access the unix location normally?

Comment: @Joe, Yeah SAS is running on UNIX.Folder structure is /tcrsk/dev/Logs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about your folder structure I can't comment on the first part of the problem.  Once the names of your logfiles are known though you can use something like the following.

The below code creates 2 datasets.  The first is just the complete log, one observation per line in the log.  The second dataset contains just those lines that have been identified as 'ERRORS'.  Note that I consider certain warnings and note statements as ERRORS as they may hide typos or other syntax or semantic issues with the code:

```
%let logfile = myfile.log;

**
** READ IN LOGFILE. CHECK FOR PROBLEMS
*;

data problems log;
  length line $1000;

  infile "&logfile";
  input;

  logfile = "&logfile";
  line_no = _n_;
  line    = _infile_;
  problem = 0;

  if 
  (
     line =: "ERROR:"
  or line =: "WARNING:"
  or line =: "NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values"
  or line =: "NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values"
  or line =: "NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values"
  or line =: "NOTE: MERGE statement has more than one data set with repeats of BY values"
  or line =: "NOTE: Invalid (or missing) arguments to the INTNX function have caused the function to return"
  or line =: "INFO: Character variables have defaulted to a length of 200"
  or line =: "NOTE: Invalid"
  )
  and not
  (
      line =: "WARNING: Your system is scheduled to expire"
  or  line =: "WARNING: The Base Product product with which Session Manager is associated"
  or  line =: "WARNING: will be expiring soon, and is currently in warning mode to indicate"
  or  line =: "WARNING: this upcoming expiration. Please run PROC SETINIT to obtain more"
  or  line =: "WARNING: information on your warning period."
  or  line =: "WARNING: This CREATE TABLE statement recursively references the target table. A consequence"
  or  line =: "WARNING: Unable to copy SASUSER registry to WORK registry. Because of this, you will not see registry customizations during this"
  or  line =: "ERROR: A lock is not available for"
  or  line =: "ERROR: Errors printed on page"
  )
  then do;
    problem = 1;
    output problems;
  end;
  output log;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Creating a dat file with the list of .log files and ERROR: in their body*/    
X 'ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/*.log | xargs grep -l "ERROR:"  
                                                > /fbrms01/dev/Logs/log_error.dat';
    data log_list; **Accessing dat fil from UNIX and creating dataset on SAS;
    infile '/fbrms01/dev/Logs/log_error.dat' dsd dlm='|' lrecl=1024; 
    input Lname :$75.; 
    run;
    options symbolgen mprint mlogic;
    %macro logfile(DS);
    %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&DS));
    /*%let obs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nobs));**To get number of observations in log_list;*/
    Proc datasets;
    Delete  All_Errors;
    %do %while (%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid)) = 0);/*To run the loop thru log_list till the end of obs*/
    %let logfile = %sysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,1));/*To get value */
            data problems ;
                length line $1000 logfile $100;
                infile "&logfile";
                input;
                logfile = "&logfile";
                line_no = _n_;
                line    = _infile_;

                if line =: "ERROR:" then do;
                output problems;
                end;
            run;
            Proc Append Base=All_Errors data=Problems force;
            Run;
        %end;
    %MEND;
    %logfile(log_list);
```

Let me know if it needs any additions....Thanks, Sam.